# Is it possible for Mojo language to include multiple dispatch feature of Julia through some hints or decorators mechanism?

Tags: programming-languages

Can the strengths of Mulitple Dispatch system of Julia language be replicated in a newly designed language like Mojo through cleverly designed mechanism? Or only Julia gets to have such a feature due to its strong type system. Can programming languages theory address this issue?